# React-router-dom как использовать функцию goBack без использования useHistory

Tags: react-router-dom

Как я могу сымитировать нажатие кнопки "назад" в браузере из кода?

```
const history = useHistory()
history.goBack()
```

я знаю, что можно и так, но как я понял в новых версиях react-router-dom useHistory изменили на useNavigate, который не имеет функции goBack(). Как можно вернуться на последнюю страницу при этом не откатывая react-router-dom?

Answer (score 1):

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate(-1);
```